# Is there a real function $f$ such that $domain(f^{(n)})\supsetneq domain(f^{(n+1)}) $ for each $n$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I was studying higher-order derivatives and I came up with the following question. I couldn't find (or deduce) information about this anywhere, so I hope you can helo me with this question.

> Is there a function $f:I\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$\mathrm{domain}(f)\supsetneq \mathrm{domain}(f') \supsetneq \mathrm{domain}(f'')\supsetneq \cdots$$
> ?

The motivation for this question comes by considering the function $f:\{x\in \mathbb{R}:x \geq 0\}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$. Its derivative is given by $f'(x)=\tfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ for $x>0$ and then $$\mathrm{domain}(f')=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x>0\}\subsetneq \mathrm{domain}(f).$$
But in this particular case we have that $$\mathrm{domain}(f^{(n)})=\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x>0\}$$ for $n\geq 1$, so this example does not work.

I hope this is not a trivial question or something. Thanks in advance for any related information.

Comment: For each $i\in\mathbb N$, you could let $f_i:(i,i+1)\to\mathbb R$ be any map which is $i$ times differentiable everywhere, but not $(i+1)$-times differentiable anywhere. By “gluing” the $f_i$’s together, you obtain a function $f$ with the desired property.

Comment: Actually, that is probably overkill, since I am implicitly relying upon the existence of a continuous everywhere but nowhere differentiable function. It just needs to be the case that each $f_i$ has a point in its domain where the $i$-th derivative exists, but the $(i+1)$-th derivative does not. With a little extra care, you could even obtain a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ in a similar manner.

Comment: Awesome. This is a pretty good way of constructing such an example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Joe's second comment is definitely the best way to look at it, I think. Defining functions piecewise and using this to patch together increasingly badly behaved functions is a powerful tool, and there's no inherent value in a function that admits a nice formula. Nevertheless, here's a nice formula :). Consider $f(x) = \lvert\sin x\rvert^{|x|/\pi + 1/2}$. The point is that near $x = n\pi$, it looks like $|x - n\pi|^{|n| + 1/2}$, which is $|n|$ times differentiable but not $(|n| + 1)$-times differentiable at $n\pi$. Working out the details is a bit horrendous though.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Yes, I really liked Joe's example because it illustrates a technique for finding such an example and this technique is often used in other kind of problems. On the other hand, your answer is brutal. I really wasn't expecting a ''closed formula''. How did you came up with such an example? It's incredible

Comment: I really want to emphasise again that there's not much mathematical or pedagogical value in my example - it's just "for sport". If I had to solve this question in a real analysis exam, I would say something like "define $f(x)$ by $f(x) = |x - 2n|^{|n| + 1/2}$ on the interval $[2n - 1, 2n + 1)$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z$". There are some standard tricks to converting this sort of thing into a nice formula. One is that $\sin$ is a nice way to get lots of zeroes, mimicking the $|x - 2n|$ part. Then I just needed to pick an exponent which takes the right value at the zeroes.

Comment: You can produce an example of a function defined on a bounded interval. $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}\left |x-{1\over n}\right |^{n-1/2},\ |x|\le 1$$